# User access logging in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to understand the Correct Way™ to administer user access logging in django. I have `axes` middleware installed, but it only seems to log failed attempts. I note the `django.contrib.auth` seems to only store the last login when I look at the admin interface. Do I have to write my own logging view (and create my own access log model if I want to be able to do useful databasey things on it?) Eg minimal example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(my_user_access_log)
def login_view(request):
    #if user is authenticated
    logger.info(user.email)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django emits a [`user_logged_in` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals) whenever a user is logged in (also similar `user_logged_out` and `user_login_failed` signals). You could attach a listener to that signal and then do your own simple logging:

```
import logging

from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def login_logger(sender, request, user):
    # Do whatever you want here with the information
    logger.info(user.email)
```

Comment: Thanks for the signal note. In the end I decided I needed more data and just added another table to the database.